Ubuntu 20.04 LTS doesn't recognize WiFi adapter (Raptor Lake)
I have a newer laptop with an older version of Ubuntu. The older version is required because it supports ROS1, and newer versions do not. However, my system doesn't recognize the wifi-adapter, and it doesn't seem to load the drivers properly. Here are my system specs:

Ubuntu version: 20.04
LTS Processor: 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13900H
Network controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
Kernel version: 5.15.0-124-generic

Running ip a the wifi-adapter is absent. Running lspci | grep Network I get the information provided above.
From what I have found in my search so far, it suggests that the necessary drivers for my wifi-adapter might not be compatible with such an old kernel version. However, I am not 100% certain of that conclusion, but I have seen some posts saying that kernel version 6.0+ is required.
I tried to find a mainline kernel version here, but all of the builds for Intel processors (i386 builds) seem to have failed, so there are no .deb files? Can I even update to newer kernels for 20.04?
My knowledge of linux in general is quite intermediate, so please take that into account.
I appreciate any help to solve this issue.
Output from sudo lshw -c network
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:622d194000-622d197fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: enx1c7c984f3f79
       serial: 1c:7c:98:4f:3f:79
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-124-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.179.5 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair

Solution
I found this thread and followed these steps which fixed the issue for me.
